# Approximate smooth path with line segments

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Can Illustrator convert a smooth path to a series of straight line segments?

I am looking to approximate a curve with line segments in a way similar to this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to do this because I plan to import the data into other software and to do some measurements on it.  It will be much easier to deal with a series of straight line segments than Bezier curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, its not really meant for this but it can be done. There is a command called **Object → Path → Simplify...** It has an option to make linear segments. Now it makes one segment per span, and you can increase the spans with **Object → Path → Add Anchor Points**.

There are also some alternate methods and script scripts that can aid in doing this.

- Make a n segmented line and make it a art or pattern brush. This allows for more accurate segment control
- [Hiroyuki Sato's scripts](http://shspage.com/aijs/en), divide as well as others (he implements a Bézier curve toolkit so you can divide as you like)

Comment: I tried it, it works well enough.